# Cointegration analysis on two time series datasets

Tags: java, statistics, time-series, regression

I am new to stats but have been practicing using the R language. I now need to perform some stats in the Java language. What I am looking to do is cointegration analysis between two-time series datasets. My problem is R handles the behind the scenes implementation of the calculations so being a novice math person I having trouble implementing this now in Java.

Looking through the web I see there is an open source library for cointegration and testing, but the methods, parameters, and data types are different then what I am used to.

The library I am referring to is from SuanShu. The following are the classes I found to be useful.

https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/stat/cointegration/CointegrationMLE.html

https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/stat/test/timeseries/adf/package-summary.html

https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/stat/cointegration/JohansenTest.html

My goal is to take two-time series datasets and simply see if they are cointegrated.

For example, if I have the following two arrays:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[]{1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};
int[] arr2 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
```

I'd first of course check if they are stationary using the ADF test which this library is simple enough.

```
double pArr1 = AugmentedDickeyFuller(arr1).pValue();
double pArr2 = AugmentedDickeyFuller(arr2).pValue();
```

Assuming they are stationary this is where I get lost of how to further use this library. Not sure which methods should be used next and the datatypes for the parameters for these methods are a little confusing. I am looking if someone could please for a simple end to end implementation of a simple test to check for cointegration between two dataset arrays. I'd prefer to stick to a library instead of trying to recreate it all myself.